# Is it possible to create a variant value type?

Tags: c#, variant

The paper [Valued Conversions](http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/papers/ValuedConversions.pdf) by Kevlin Henney gives a motivation for a so-called variant value type functionality, as well as an outline of a C++ implementation. It is a good read and it covers exactly what I would like to have available in C#: a general type that can hold values of different [value-types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any/reference.html#any.ValueType).

I have not been able to find anything like this in C# though. Somewhat similar questions on SO have unsatisfactory answers and comments like "this is probably not what you want". This surprises me because it looks like fairly commonly required functionality. Henney's C++ [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html) class is widely used.

Is it not possible to create this functionality in C#?

---

Edit: Responding to one of the answers, I do not think that generics will do the trick. Using a generic requires the developer to know what kind of value-type the `Variant` variable is holding, and that type becomes immutable for that particular `Variant` variable as well. But the `Variant` type I am talking about should be able to hold different types. For example, a function `Variant ReadValue()` could read an entry from a file, parse it, fill the `Variant` value accordingly and then return it. The caller does not know in advance what kind of type will be contained in the returned `Variant`.

Comment: What about just declaring it as type `Object`?

Comment: @bhamlin Would using `Object` be appropriate? I do not know, since I am fairly new to C#. That approach sounds too generic to my liking though, since an `Object` can basically be anything, including non-value-types.

Answer (score 5):

This is what generics are for. `List<T>` where `T` is anything at all. Generics provide both compile-time and runtime type safety.

You could create your own generic type to store any value you want. You could also cast anything to `object` and pass it around as such.

You can also use generic constraints to limit your type, such as wanting to only have `T` be a reference type:

```
public MyClass<T> where T : class
```

Or a value type:

```
public MyClass<T> where T : struct
```

See more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: You cannot restrict a generic type to `ValueType`.

Comment: @Servy: Better worded as 'you mean `struct` not `ValueType`'.

Comment: Thanks @Servy and @Magus - corrected my error and forgot about that. I always think you *can* do that because you can limit to reference types via `new()`

Comment: You *can*! It's just `struct` in that situation!

Comment: @Magus I was hoping he'd figure it out on his own.  Sadly he's changed it to something that compiles, but makes no sense in this context.

Comment: True, but wording it as you did doesn't encourage him to even consider that it's still possible.

Comment: `new()` does not force it to be a reference type.  In fact, since all value types *must* have a parameterless constructor, they all meet that constraint.

Comment: @Servy - condescention aside, corrected. Thanks for the positive input!

Comment: I have added an explanation why I do not think that a generic does what I am looking for.

Comment: @Reinier - you could do this with the `dynamic` type which is checked at runtime versus compile time. You could also do this with some very creative reflection.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into using [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) for this as well.

> The dynamic type enables the operations in which it occurs to bypass compile-time type checking. Instead, these operations are resolved at run time.
>
> Type dynamic behaves like type object in most circumstances. However, operations that contain expressions of type dynamic are not resolved or type checked by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Henney's article is quite old (year 2000). In a live lesson (London DevWeek 2008) I remember him explaining low coupling and implementing towards abstractions (interfaces) for the OCP (Open-Closed Principle). He was quite fond of generics and more so generic interfaces. So conceptually it's most probably *exactly* what he has written about back then, albeit I must admit I didn't read the article. C# generics are even a bit more robust then C++ templates, you should look at [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

On another note:

What you can't do with generics are [variable arity templates](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/racket/pubs/NU-CCIS-08-01.pdf), which have been available for C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, using `any` in C++ is same as using combination of `object` and [ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method in C# with exception of having nice syntax for autoconversion from and into the any type. And without limitation just for value types.